# Explanation of $\equiv$, and which of these statements involving it are true?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am not familiar with this three lines equal sign and reading about it didnt really help with the original problem, which is:

> From the options below choose up to two that show correct solutions
>   for each of the three calculations:

The photo of the options:

> [image]

Little help?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic explains what the "three lines equal symbol" is.

Comment: if it is not a hassle for you, could you please suggest one correct option so that i could work out how it works for myself. As it still looks confusing :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A-1 : $4+11 = 15$. Is $15$ equal to $2$ modulo $13$ ? It is the case since $15-2 = 13 = 1\times 13$. **true.**

A-2 : $9+7 = 16$. Is $16$ equal to $4$ modulo $12$ ? It is the case since $16-4 = 12 = 1\times 12$. **true.**

A-3 : $13+13=26$. Is $26$ equal to $1$ modulo $25$ ? It is the case since $26-1 = 25 = 1\times 25$. **true.**

Comment: For a positive integer n, two integers a and b are said to be congruent modulo n (or a is congruent to b modulo n), if a and b have the same remainder when divided by n (or equivalently if a − b is divisible by n ). It can be expressed as a ≡ b mod n. n is called the modulus.

Comment: thanks for your help Justt. The link i found useful http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~mrh/330tutor/ch03.html

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the $\equiv$ symbol is [explained here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Congruence_relation). Understanding that explanation, you can see that the statement
$$x+y\equiv z\bmod n$$
means the same thing as (and therefore, has the same truth value as)
$$x+y-z\;\;\text{ is divisible by }n,$$
or in other words,
$$x+y-z\;\;\text{ is equal to }n\text{ times an integer}.$$
For example, is
$$17+9\equiv 4\bmod 21$$
true? No, because
$$17+9-4=22\;\;\text{ is }{\large\textbf{not}}\text{ a multiple of 21}.$$
Use this to evaluate each of the three statements in each of the six options.

Comment: Thanks Zev. I definitely got it :)